# Update a value by nearest polygon

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-3, spatial-join

I'm looking to be able to update a value by its nearest polygon.

The below image shows polygons in green where the column roadclass = 'A' and shows polygons where column roadclass IS NULL in brown.

I'm manually selecting and updating these currently so would like to automate it if possible.

[image]

[image]

I'm keen to learn but I've not used python before in QGIS so please consider this in any response. Also if useful the layer is stored within a PostGIS database and I'm using QGIS 3.6.

Comment: what do you want to update? Can you share the screen shot of the tables?

Comment: I want to be able to update the null values based on the value from the nearest polygon. So as an example above I'd be wanting all the null values to be replaced with 'A'

Comment: yes, but can you share the table structure?

Comment: @ayaz49 added above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this answers your question,

```
update your_table
set roadclass  =sub.nearest_value
from
 (
 SELECT 
      p.idd as updating_id,b.id2 as nearest_id, b.roadclass  as 
  nearest_value
  FROM  (
   --selecting id and geom of null values 
   SELECT gid AS idd, geom
    FROM your_table where roadclass  is null
  ) p
  --finding nearest polygon and its of the selected ids.
    ,LATERAL (
  --the nearest columns you want to update
  SELECT b.gid as id2,b.roadclass  
  FROM   your_table b
  where b.gid<>p.idd and b.roadclass is not null
  ORDER BY  b.geom <->(p.geom )
  LIMIT  1
  ) b
  ORDER  BY idd,id2
          )sub
   where your_table.gid=sub.updating_id;
```

Comment: Just to be clear sorry - you suggest running this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Yes run this query in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Got the following but with no change to the null values.

"UPDATE 2177

Query returned successfully in 2 secs 159 msec."

Comment: Yes because all null values are updated from its nearest polygon's value.

Comment: Okay so this might have worked sorry - I previously had 2177 null values but now i have only 1404. Is it worth running this a number of times and do you know how the nearest is calculated? Does it use the polygon centroid?

Comment: I have updated the answer, run it again.

Comment: No you need to run it only once, all the null values are updated from nearby values. Previously,  some null values were updating from nearest null values but now I have used condition that update from those that are not null.

Comment: Thanks, @ayaz49 - this definitely works although I might need to tweak it further as I've got some anomalies. Massive thanks for your help!!

Comment: Welcome ,you also run this query on a new table, may be the previous query might have updated the records not as expected?

Comment: Possibly - I'll do some tests my end but I think its more to do with my data than your query.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ST_ClusterDBSCAN to cluster adjacent polygons together and then assign class by most frequent class in that cluster group:

```
--Add a temp column holding cluster id
alter table sometable add column cid int;
update sometable
set cid = sub.clusterid
from (SELECT *, ST_ClusterDBSCAN(geom, eps := 0, minpoints := 1) OVER () clusterid
    FROM sometable) sub
where sometable.id = sub.id;

--Update column "value" with the most common value in each cluster
update sometable
set value = sub.mode
from (select mode() within group (order by value), cid
from sometable
group by cid) sub
where sometable.cid = sub.cid;

alter table sometable drop column cid;
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @BERA thanks for this - could you evolve this further to only do this on clusters of polygons with the same unique identifier? (.e.g road names) I've got a large dataset and each road is could have a seperate value.